# Cannot login to newly installed Debian 12, stuck on the login screen

Tags: debian, system-installation, password

I’ve successfully installed Debian 12 and upon reboot, I’m attempting to login to the desktop environment for the first time. After I type in the password on the login screen, the following screen flashes briefly and I’m taken back to the login screen.

[image]

If I change username to root and try to login with my root password on the login screen, the screen will shake, telling me I don't have the right password.  (I made sure the password is correct)

I am, however, able to press ctrl+alt+f3 to get the CLI and I am able to login using both my user account name/pw and root.

Anyone know why I can't login to the desktop environment? What's causing this and how I can fix it?

I have KDE Plasma installed and here are my specs:

MB: B550I AORUS PRO AX Resolution: 2560×1440, 2560×1440 CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 5600X (12) @ 3.700GH GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Memory: 32044MiB

Comment: Did you install from the netinst image or the "live" KDE image? Personally, I'd try other DE's - perhaps KDE is broken on 12 - I have no reason to think it would be, but, new release and all that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So on the login screen, there are two desktop sessions: Plasma (Wayland) and Plasma (X11).

[image]

When I switched to Plasma (X11), I was able to login.

Not sure why there are two sessions, that will be another question.